# Bot de Discord no lee los comandos (node.js)

Tags: nodejs, discord.js

Estoy intentando que el bot lea una variedad de comandos para saber que le pasa.

Les dejo el archivo index, junto con el mensaje de la consola.

**Archivo index.js**

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, ChatInputCommandInteraction, Message, Collection, ReactionManager, ReactionCollector, ReactionEmoji } = require('discord.js');
// const Discord = require('discord.js');
const configuracion = require('./config.json');
const prefijo = configuracion.prefix;
const { SlashCommandBuilder, chatInputApplicationCommandMention } = require('@discordjs/builders');
require('dotenv').config();
// const TOKEN = require('dotenv');
// const bot = new Discord.Client();
require('discord-reply');
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let { readdirSync } = require('fs');
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, './lib/general/comandos');
const commandsFile = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file =>file.endsWith('.js'));
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Escaneo de ficheros
for (const file of commandsFile) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    }
    else {
        console.log(`[CUIDADO] El comando en ${filePath} le falta unos datos requeridos o una ejecucion correcta.`)
    }
}
// Aqui me funciona
client.once(Events.ClientReady, (message) => {
    // if (message.author.bot) return;
    console.log(`Conectado como: ${client.user.tag}`)
    // if (!message.content.startsWith(configuracion.prefix)) return;

    /**
     * Una forma que es valida, pero es muy "perjudicial";
     * seria que hubiese que escribir una linea de codigo y copiarla por cada canal de texto,
     * ya que estamos hablando de que serian miles de canales de texto
     */
});
/** 
 * En el siguiente codigo,
 * tengo que escribir cosas en ingles para que lo reconozca el lenguaje de programacion, sino no funciona,
 * Lo digo porque para que se entienda mejor, poner lo que se pueda en español.
 */
client.on(ChatInputCommandInteraction, message => {
    if (message.MessageContent = prefijo) {
        message.reply(`Has contestado con el prefijo! \n Genial!`)
    }
});

client.on(chatInputApplicationCommandMention.commandName, interaction => {
    if (interaction.content = "hola") {
        interaction.reply('Hola muy buenas.');
    }
});

client.on(ChatInputCommandInteraction, message => {
    if (message.MessageContent = "hola") {
        message.reply(`Hola muy buenas!`)
    }
});
client.on('interactionCreate', async(interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const comando = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!comando) return;

    try{
        await comando.execute(interaction, log);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({content: 'Hubo un error mientras se ejecutaba este comando', ephemeral: true});
    }
});
console.log(prefijo + "hola");
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hola')
        .setDescription('Envia mensaje de bienvenida'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Hola muy buenas!');
    },
};
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'hola') {
        await interaction.reply("Hola muy buenas.")
    }
});

client.login(process.env["TOKEN"]);
```

**Consola:**

> PS D:\proyectoMart> node .\index.js 
> vp-hola 
> Conectado como: Virgen de la Paz bot#3229

Estoy usando:

- nodejs v18.12
- discord.js v14.6.0 (ya que use la guia de discord.js)

PD: Si al replicar el código les muestra error del Token, por motivos de seguridad no lo coloco.

el config.json es el siguiente:

```
{   "prefix": "vp-",   "idioma":"espanol"  }
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta estas 3 cosas:

1. Agrega el intent `GuildMessages` a tu bot.

```
    const client = new Client({ 
      intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
      ]
    });
```

2. Agrega el evento 'messageCreate'.
   Este evento es el encargado de esperar los mensajes, ningún otro evento hace esto.

```
    client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
      const args = message.content.slice(configuracion.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      // comando de prueba 'ping'
      if (command === 'ping') {
        message.reply({ content: 'Pong!' });
      }
    });
```

3. Activa el intent `Message content intent` en [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Espero te ayude.